# Is there a way to link to files in a Git commit snapshot from outside the clone directory WITHOUT doing a checkout?

Tags: git

I have been using Git for awhile to do revision control and contribute to project code.  Lately, I have also been considering using Git to provide revision control for a directory that various parties need to linking to in order to read files.  They would also be interested in being able to link to these files/directories in the repo for any commit snapshot of their choosing, but the only way I currently know to do this is to write a script that does a checkout of the desired commit in the linked directory (or a clone) and link to the directory path.  This is undesirable because multiple parties are linking to this directory, and we do not want to move the HEAD.  It would also be a lighter weight procedure if each user did not have to clone or sparsely clone each time they wanted to read these files.

Is there anything in the Git porcelain or plumbing that would allow reading files in this root directory clone for any commit from outside?  I am envisioning something such as a plumbing-based directory path to a pointer to the snapshot, but I'm pretty sure that isn't quite how Git is structured.  Does anyone have any tips?  Thanks!

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to grab a copy of a file from a commit, without checking out that commit, is that correct? You can try this command: `git cat-file -p -- commithash:path\to\file`

Comment: This was a cool way to view the file.  Do you happen to know if there is a way to reference the file via a path?  For instance, if I want to execute code from a file in a given commit, is there something like this that would let me?

Comment: @irregularExpression I'd suggest that you shouldn't do that. If you're depending on code in a certain commit, just put that code in as a file in your repo.

Comment: That's the thing though.  That commit's file already IS a file in my repo.  That's why I was hoping I could take advantage of being able to go right to the version of that file I want.  If this is even possible as I described (circumventing the checkout), what is the harm?

Comment: The only files that are on disk in a readable form by other programs are those that are checked out to your working folder. You will need to check out a file for it to become readable by anything other than git. You can always **extract** a file, like I showed, but you will need to write it somewhere for it to become useful to other programs. In the git repository the file is compressed and not really usable.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense to me.  Thank you guys for commenting!